# SageMaker in local Jupyter notebook: cannot use AWS hosted XGBoost container ("KeyError: 'S3DistributionType'" and "Failed to run: ['docker-compose'")

Tags: python, docker, jupyter-notebook, xgboost, amazon-sagemaker

Running SageMaker within a local Jupyter notebook (using VS Code) works without issue, except that attempting to train an XGBoost model using the AWS hosted container results in errors (container name: `246618743249.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/sagemaker-xgboost:1.0-1-cpu-py3`).

### Jupyter Notebook

```py
import sagemaker

session = sagemaker.LocalSession()

# Load and prepare the training and validation data
...

# Upload the training and validation data to S3
test_location = session.upload_data(os.path.join(data_dir, 'test.csv'), key_prefix=prefix)
val_location = session.upload_data(os.path.join(data_dir, 'validation.csv'), key_prefix=prefix)
train_location = session.upload_data(os.path.join(data_dir, 'train.csv'), key_prefix=prefix)

region = session.boto_region_name
instance_type = 'ml.m4.xlarge'
container = sagemaker.image_uris.retrieve('xgboost', region, '1.0-1', 'py3', instance_type=instance_type)

role = 'arn:aws:iam::<USER ID #>:role/service-role/AmazonSageMaker-ExecutionRole-<ROLE ID #>'

xgb_estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container, role, train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type=instance_type,
    output_path=f's3://{session.default_bucket()}/{prefix}/output', sagemaker_session=session)

xgb_estimator.set_hyperparameters(max_depth=5, eta=0.2, gamma=4, min_child_weight=6,
                                  subsample=0.8, objective='reg:squarederror', early_stopping_rounds=10,
                                  num_round=200)

s3_input_train = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data=train_location, content_type='csv')
s3_input_validation = sagemaker.inputs.TrainingInput(s3_data=val_location, content_type='csv')

xgb_estimator.fit({'train': s3_input_train, 'validation': s3_input_validation})
```

### Docker Container KeyError

```
algo-1-tfcvc_1  | ERROR:sagemaker-containers:Reporting training FAILURE
algo-1-tfcvc_1  | ERROR:sagemaker-containers:framework error: 
algo-1-tfcvc_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_containers/_trainer.py", line 84, in train
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     entrypoint()
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 94, in main
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     train(framework.training_env())
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 90, in train
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     run_algorithm_mode()
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/training.py", line 68, in run_algorithm_mode
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     checkpoint_config=checkpoint_config
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_xgboost_container/algorithm_mode/train.py", line 115, in sagemaker_train
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     validated_data_config = channels.validate(data_config)
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit/channel_validation.py", line 106, in validate
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     channel_obj.validate(value)
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |   File "/miniconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sagemaker_algorithm_toolkit/channel_validation.py", line 52, in validate
algo-1-tfcvc_1  |     if (value[CONTENT_TYPE], value[TRAINING_INPUT_MODE], value[S3_DIST_TYPE]) not in self.supported:
algo-1-tfcvc_1  | KeyError: 'S3DistributionType'
```

### Local PC Runtime Error

```
RuntimeError: Failed to run: ['docker-compose', '-f', '/tmp/tmp71tx0fop/docker-compose.yaml', 'up', '--build', '--abort-on-container-exit'], Process exited with code: 1
```

If the Jupyter notebook is run using the Amazon cloud SageMaker environment (rather than on the local PC), there are no errors. Note that when running on the cloud notebook, the session is initialized as:

```
session = sagemaker.Session()
```

It appears that there is an issue with how the `LocalSession()` works with the hosted docker container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When running SageMaker in a local Jupyter notebook, it expects the Docker container to be running on the local machine as well.

The key to ensuring that SageMaker (running in a local notebook) uses the AWS hosted docker container, is to omit the `LocalSession` object when initializing the `Estimator`.

### Wrong

```
xgb_estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container, role, train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type=instance_type,
    output_path=f's3://{session.default_bucket()}/{prefix}/output', sagemaker_session=session)
```

### Correct

```
xgb_estimator = sagemaker.estimator.Estimator(
    container, role, train_instance_count=1, train_instance_type=instance_type,
    output_path=f's3://{session.default_bucket()}/{prefix}/output')
```

### Additional info

The SageMaker Python SDK source code provides the following helpful hints:

## File: *sagemaker/local/local_session.py*

```
class LocalSagemakerClient(object):
    """A SageMakerClient that implements the API calls locally.

    Used for doing local training and hosting local endpoints. It still needs access to
    a boto client to interact with S3 but it won't perform any SageMaker call.
    ...
```

## File: *sagemaker/estimator.py*

```
class EstimatorBase(with_metaclass(ABCMeta, object)):
    """Handle end-to-end Amazon SageMaker training and deployment tasks.

    For introduction to model training and deployment, see
    http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/how-it-works-training.html

    Subclasses must define a way to determine what image to use for training,
    what hyperparameters to use, and how to create an appropriate predictor instance.
    """

    def __init__(self, role, train_instance_count, train_instance_type,
                 train_volume_size=30, train_max_run=24 * 60 * 60, input_mode='File',
                 output_path=None, output_kms_key=None, base_job_name=None, sagemaker_session=None, tags=None):
        """Initialize an ``EstimatorBase`` instance.

        Args:
            role (str): An AWS IAM role (either name or full ARN). ...
            
        ...

            sagemaker_session (sagemaker.session.Session): Session object which manages interactions with
                Amazon SageMaker APIs and any other AWS services needed. If not specified, the estimator creates one
                using the default AWS configuration chain.
        """
```